# VBA Web Automation on a dynamic site

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, webautomation

I am trying to scrap barcode owners from this site : http://gepir.gs1.org/index.php/search-by-gtin

I am receiving "Object doesnt support this property or method" error msg because of the final line. I tried to extract it with class and tag but failed.

I am trying to extract the company name from the dynamic table.

```
Sub aa()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim aaa As Object
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "gepir.gs1.org/index.php/search-by-gtin"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Debug.Print ie.LocationName, ie.LocationURL

Set doc = ie.document

ie.document.forms("searchbygtin").elements("keyValue").Value = "685387379712"
ie.document.forms("searchbygtin").elements("method").Click

Debug.Print ie.document.getElementsBytag("tr")(7).innerText

End Sub
```

Any help would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need TagName

```
Debug.Print ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(7).innerText
```

I get a captcha though so I doubt you can complete this task in this way. Selenium and IE both seem to trigger the captcha, at least for me.

---

If not for the captcha I would re-write your script as follows (perhaps with a loop to make sure tr element is present):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetLastChangeDate()
    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument
    Const URL = "gepir.gs1.org/index.php/search-by-gtin"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set doc = .document

        Debug.Print .LocationName, .LocationURL

        doc.getElementById("keyValue").Value = "685387379712"
        doc.getElementById("submit-button").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Debug.Print .document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(7).innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, I am still receiving "Object doesn't support this property or method" msg, did the code work for you?

Comment: Sorry that is the error msg "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Yes. But I have to manually complete the autocaptcha on screen and then F8 back through the code to click the button and then retrieve Last Change DateApr. 18, 2015

Comment: That error message happens because there is a captcha you cannot get past with automation in this way. In fact in anyway I know except with a complex robot beyond my abilities to program. You will need to find a different way. Is there an API? The original problem you had was because of the missing Name part though.

Comment: Let me know if you consider this answered. When IE opens and you scroll down do you see the captcha?

Comment: no, it is not asking captcha from me but it looks like I've exceeded the query limit. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok.. any problems let me know and I can offer you an addition to the code to loop until element is present.

Comment: Can I have if it won't take your too much time :) still improving myself on web scraping it will be very useful